# Difference Between Local Nominatim and OpenStreetMap Website results

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, nominatim

I have installed nominatim 4.1.0 (tokenizer= ICU) via following instructions  on [nominatim documentation](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/), added wikipedia data during the installation, and imported an updated pbf file from [geofabrik.de](https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/italy/isole.html).

All works but when I sent some kind of request (e.g. *Cagliari via Roma*) the answer I get from Nominatim Website (https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/) and my local installation are very different. The right results are on nominatim website of course.

The problems seems to be with the search candidate algorithm  or the attribuition/calc of *AdressImportance* parameter.
The very strange thing is that I get these wrong results only for some requests.

There is any particular parameter to set or anything else to verify?

I hope it is clear for you and even small advice or comment would be very helpful for me

Thanks
Michele

Answer (score 1):

After a discussion with the maintainers (https://github.com/osm-search/Nominatim/discussions/2839), I found an acceptable solution by editing the Geocode.php file line as follows:

```
$this->iLimit = $iLimit + max($iLimit, 150)
```

the result is not exactly the same as that of the [online version](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html) but it works fine for me